# Excel cell values containing times are reported as 12 hour instead of 24 hour with JExcelApi

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I need to read an Excel document and extract some cell values for further processing.  I use JExcelAPI for this.  This works well.

We need to have a cell containing wall time as a four character string (like "0810" for ten past eight and "1550" for ten to four) which is achived by calculating the time and custom formatting it with the "ttmm" minute pattern.  ("t" is 24 hour in the Danish locale.  This is in Denmark which currently is GMT+2, and our Windows machines are with English locale)

My problem is now that when I read in the cells with `cell.getContents()` the first cell is correctly "0810" but the second is "0350" instead of "1550".  I do not have a deep understanding of jxl so I do not know if that value comes straight from the sheet as generated by Excel when saving or is generated deep down in jxl at runtime.  Manipulating the Date stored in the DateCell is also cumbersome as the timezone is wrong, and we have other date cells which does not need this treatment.

I was also thinking if we can do the calculations in a field not read, and then convert the contents to a four character string in a field read?

So, how can I get the times in the form I need?

(Note: I will award a 500 point bounty for the most helpful answer.  I just cannot open it yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a solution.

We ended up in coercing the date into the desired text string in Excel itself (in a different cell, and ignoring the date cell when reading the sheet in Java).